# Stripe laravel Call to undefined method error

Tags: php, laravel

I try to make a charge with stripe Laravel Catalyst but I get a Call to undefined method Cartalyst\Stripe\Stripe::charges().Here is my code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $charge= Stripe::charges()->create([
        'amount'=> '10.00',
        'currency'=>'USD',
        'source'=>$request->stripeToken,
        'description'=>'Order',
        'metadata'=>[

        ]
      ]);





        return back()->with('success_message', 'Thank You! Your payment has been successfully accepted!');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the right method?

Comment: In the documentation is ok $charge = $stripe->charges()->create([
    'customer' => 'cus_4EBumIjyaKooft',
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'amount'   => 50.49,
]);

Comment: From looking at the documentation, you may need to do it differently. Create the object with `$stripe = Stripe::make('your-stripe-api-key');` and then you should be able to call `$stripe->charges()`

Comment: Probably you attach wrong class at the top, cause there is no `charges()` method in Cartalyst\Stripe\Stripe class

Comment: I see I will look more.

Comment: Please controller put here

Comment: @MarkWilliam Did you follow the steps? https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe-laravel/8.x

Answer (score 1):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $stripe = Stripe::make('test_api_key');
        $charge= $stripe->charges()->create([
        'amount' => $request['amount'],
        'currency' =>'USD',
        'source' =>$request->stripeToken,
        'description' =>'Order',
        'metadata' =>[

        ],
      ]);



        return back()->with('success_message', 'Thank You! Your payment has been successfully accepted!');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return back()->withErrors('Error! '. $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```